# Columns that are created during SELECT do no exists

Tags: python, sqlite, cs50, keyerror

I am trying to retrieve data from a sqlite data base. The goal is to get the sum of expenses per day.
The code: (it is not correctly formatted)

```
db = SQL("sqlite:///financetracker.db")

test = db.execute("""
        SELECT SUM(amount) AS total_amount, strftime('%Y', timestamp) AS year, strftime('%m', timestamp) AS month, STRFTIME('%d', timestamp) AS day
        FROM transactions
        WHERE exp = 1 AND user_id = 1 AND year = strftime('%Y', 'now') AND month = strftime('%m', 'now')
        GROUP BY year, month, day
        ORDER by timestamp DESC
        """)
```

I am using the sql module from the cs50 library. *exp* is a column that contains booleans. This way I filter out the expenses.

As you can see, during the SELECT I add three additional columns: *year*, *month* and *day* and I calculate the sum per day. The dates are taken from another timestamp column in the same table. In this case *test* should be a list of dictionaries.
The outcome looks like this:

| total_amount | year | month | day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6.5 | 2021 | 01 | 29 |
| 20 | 2021 | 01 | 28 |

The SELECT works perfectly when I do it in phpliteadmin. Every column appears. But  for some reasons the shown python script does not return the columns *year*, *month* and *day*. Only *total_amount*.

The following code:

```
day_1 = test[0]['day']
```

results in a key error:

```
KeyError: 'day'
```

Comment: Please show the code that gets the error.

Comment: @Barmer I just added the code and made some other improvements.

Comment: Can you show how you set up the Python DB connection e.g. `fetchall()`

Comment: @Mark I added one line of code. That's all I did to connect the DB. This functionality comes within the SQL module of cs50.

Comment: Something happened to `test` between the execute and `day_1 = test[0]['day']`.  That sql will return dictionaries with all 4 keys whenever rows are selected. If no rows are selected this `day_1 = test[0]['day']` would give a different error (index out of range).

Comment: The python code that you have posted doesn't work by itself. I have no idea which package you have imported `SQL` from. I suspect you need to fetch the rows before accessing them - with fetch() or fetchall()

Comment: @Mark I am using the cs50 library. And the only thing you have to do to connect the DB is  the first line of code in my example.

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus I know, it's weird. And for some reason, `day_1 = test[0]['total_amount']` works.

Comment: What do you get if you do `print(test[0])`? That will show the structure of the row output

Comment: By "something happened" I mean there is code that changes `test` before the line that fails.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you all for you input. I just solved it. For some reasons the columns *day*, *month* and *year* were all in capital letters. I don't know why, as I clearly wrote them in lowercase.
What's even weirder is that *total_amount* stayed lowercase in the dict.

That means that by typing `day_1 = test[0]['DAY']` I solved it.